# Try-except error handling for functions that return boolean values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, error-handling

I have a pandas dataframe where if there are non-unique index values, I would like to raise an exception in a try-except block. I basically want to try to test whether the index values are unique, and if not, return an exception. If they are unique, return the dataframe.
Below is an attempt (that doesn't work)

```
def read_df(file):
  df = pd.read_table(file).set_index("filename", drop=True)
  while True:
        try:
            df.index.is_unique is True
        except Exception:
            sys.exit("File names are not unique")
        else:
            return df
```

What is the best practice for writing try-except blocks with boolean values?

**Edit**:

Would this be more correct in a try/except block?

```
def read_df(file):
  df = pd.read_table(file).set_index("filename", drop=True)
  try:
      if df.index.nunique()!= len(df):
           raise Exception
  except:
      sys.exit("File names are not unique.")
  else:
      return df
```

Comment: Unless you expect an `AttributeError` from `df.index.is_unique`, the expression is simply going to be `True` or `False`, not something that raise an exception to catch.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see an Exception, you either code your own function to raise an Exception (using `raise`) or use a function/method that has been defined to raise an Exception which is, in your case, how we should proceed because `sys.exit` does raise an `SystemExit` exception.

There are many ways to check if all index/column values are unique, one of such is `df.index.nunique() == len(df)`. `nunique` gives you the number of unique values, and if that number is equal to the number of rows of the dataframe, then obviously every index value is unique. Another method is `pandas.Index.duplicated` (check [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) out)

```
def read_df(file):
  df = pd.read_table(file).set_index("filename", drop=True)
  if df.index.nunique() != len(df):
    sys.exit("File names are not unique")
  else:
    return df
```

I removed the while loop here as it's not necessary.

**EDIT**

Your new code will work. When `df.index.nunique()!= len(df)` is `True`, it raises its first exception of `Exception`, and enter the `except` block where it will raise its second exception of `SystemExit` and do the system exit action.

Another way to write your code, not necessarily look better, is

```
def read_df(file):
  df = pd.read_table(file).set_index("filename", drop=True)
  try:
      if df.index.nunique()!= len(df):
           raise Exception("File names are not unique.")
      elif some_condition2
           raise Exception("Condition2 satisfied")
  except Exception as e:
      print(e) # print exception message of the satisfied condition
      sys.exit()
  else:
      return df
```

---

And now we keep using `Exception` here but indeed there are more dedicated notations that carries narrower meanings (e.g. ZeroDivisionError, ValueError).

[Ref1: Exception in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#exceptions)

[Ref2: List of built-in Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html)

Good thing of using that is you can handle different exception differently, such as

```
try:
    if (condition1):
        raise ZeroDivisionError('message1')
    elif (condition2):
        raise ValueError('message2')
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    print(e)
    handle_approach_1(...)
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
    handle_approach_2(...)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    handle_of_anyother_exceptions_not_catched_above(...)
```

You may (or may not ;) ) think that ZeroDivisionError and ValueError are so irrelevant to you that such way of handling Exception is not needed, but the truth is many python packages such as `pandas` and web-crawling tools define their own sets of Exception keywords and if you want to handle different critical exceptions in different manner, this is how you want to program your try-except block.

Finally, do also check out `finally` as sometimes it is being used together with `try-except`.

[One reference for finally](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/try-except-else-and-finally-in-python/)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! This makes sense to me but I am more-so trying to learn how to handle functions in try/except blocks that return boolean values? I edited my question to include another example of an attempt.

Comment: In short, your attempt is ok. I have also edited my answer for more responses.